# good covers and simplicial maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a paracompact topological space and choose a good cover $U_i$ of $X$. Remember that a good cover is one that consists of open subsets, such that each set $U_i$ is contractible and all finite intersections $U_{i_1} \cap U_{i_2} \cap \dots \cap U_{i_k}$ are either empty or contractible.

This induces a simplicial topological space $U_{\bullet}$. Let $Z_{\bullet}$ be another simplicial topological space. I keep reading that any continuous map
$$
f \colon |U_{\bullet}| \to |Z_{\bullet}|
$$
is homotopic to a simplicial one (e.g. in the sketched proof of theorem 4.5 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306027)). Is there any reference for this? How do I prove this?

Comment: This is an easy corollary of the well-known simplicial approximation theorem.

Comment: But isn't the simplicial approximation theorem (at least as I know it) a statement about simplicial complexes and not about simplicial spaces? See also <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90480/simplicial-approximation-for-simplicial-spaces">this</a> question. 

Comment: sorry for the broken link. I meant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90480/simplicial-approximation-for-simplicial-spaces

Comment: The property stated above is not correct (as suggests the link). What is true is that, there exists another good cover $U'$ of $X$ and a morphism of simplicial spaces $U'_\bullet\to Z_\bullet$ whose realization is homotopic to $f$ under the weak homotopy equivalences $|U_\bullet|\sim X\sim |U'_\bullet|$.

Comment: @Ulrich: Sorry, I took simplicial complex for simplicial space.

Comment: @Fernando: No problem. Maybe there is some variant of the simplicial approximation theorem that works in this case, but the only thing I can find is the work by Jardine, who only works with simplicial sets.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski Is there a reference for the sort of result mentioned in your comment? I've found that I need something of this sort in a project I'm working on.